# MySQL query to group by two columns?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a table that has the following columns:

Sale Amount, Country, Date_of_Sale (MM/DD/YYYY)

I need to produce a query that can give me a COUNT of sales per country per date of sale and can look like something like this:

### `COUNT COUNTRY DATE_OF_SALE`

### `1000  USA     4/1/2016`

### `500   USA     4/2/2016`

### `2000  CN      4/1/2016`

### `3000  CN      4/2/2016`

For the life of me I can't seem to find something that works. The table contains over 30 days of information and I wanted to build this so that I can see historical sales values by date by country. I've tried:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS C1, COUNTRY, DATE_OF SALE FROM DB.TABLE ORDER BY DATE_OF_SALE DESC;
```

... That just gives me total count of the entire table on column1, a random (probably the top?) country, and only one date... not sure what is going on. Sorry, not a MySQL expert but can any one help? I'm still searching for an answer on Google to see what comes up, thought I might post this first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give it a column to count, and group the rest:

```
select count(country) as COUNT, COUNTRY, DATE_OF_SALE
from DB.TABLE ORDER BY DATE_OF_SALE DESC
group by COUNTRY, DATE_OF_SALE
```

That should do the trick.  Except that you're counting one of the thing's you're returning.  You should find another column and count that.  Usually a unique ID is the best.